# Rearranging the order of flows, not nodes, in a ggsankey diagram

Tags: r, ggplot2, sankey-diagram

I'm trying to construct a sankey diagram in R using ggsankey. I have three levels/stages as shown in the figure below. The level in the middle shows some inflow ("In") and outflow ("Out"). As a bit of hack, I've introduced a dummy in stage2 just to increase the vertical spacing. Setting `node.color = 0` makes the dummy invisible, which is good enough for me.

I have ordered the nodes both in the nodes and in the legend by setting `node` and `next_node` to factors and tweaking the `breaks` setting in `scale_fill_discrete`. This is all fine.

However, I would like also like to order the flows, not just the nodes. Specifically, I want the inflow from stage2 (In) to stage3 (A) to end up above the flow from stage1 (A) to stage3 (A) and also above the flow from stage1 (B) to stage3 (A). So in essence, I don't want the flows to cross.

How can I achieve that?

[Current result where the flow of node "In" from stage2 to stage3 is not in the right order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ec0pK.png)

Here's the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsankey)

test <- tribble(
  ~x, ~node, ~next_x, ~next_node, ~value,
  "stage1", "A", "stage3", "A", 10,
  "stage3", "A", NA, NA, 10,
  "stage1", "B", "stage3", "A", 2,
  "stage3", "A", NA, NA, 2,
  "stage1", "A", "stage2", "Out", 5,
  "stage2", "Out", NA, NA, 5,
  "stage2", "In", "stage3", "A", 3,
  "stage3", "A", NA, NA, 3,
  "stage2", "Dummy", NA, NA, 20
) %>% 
  mutate(node = factor(node, levels = c("Out", "Dummy", "A", "B", "In")),
         next_node = factor(next_node, levels = c("Out", "Dummy", "A", "B", "In"))) %>% 
  mutate(x = factor(x, levels = c("stage1", "stage2", "stage3")),
         next_x = factor(next_x, levels = c("stage1", "stage2", "stage3")))

ggplot(test,
       aes(x = x, node = node, next_x = next_x, next_node = next_node, value = value)) +
  geom_sankey(aes(fill = node, alpha = node),
              flow.alpha = 0.5,
              node.color = 1,  # Set to zero to make dummy invisible
              flow.color = 1) +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("In", "B", "A", "Out")) + 
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("Dummy" = 0)) +
  guides(alpha = "none")
```

Thanks so much!